# Get CheckBoxes values to Array or List with Javascripts or Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, checkbox

I want to get values into an array (checkslist) from checked checkboxes. I tried this code but it does not seems to work. In the `for` I can get  "checkslist"s items which is push but after `for` it can't. How can I get all the checked CheckBoxes's values into an array or list?

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnEkle").click(
    function() {
      var checkbox, checkslist, menuId, text, vModel;
      checkslist = [];
      checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checks");

      for (var i = 0; checkbox.length; ++i) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked) {
          menuId = checkbox[i].value;
          checkslist.push(menuId);
        }
      }      
      alert(checkslist[0].value)
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your for loop,

```
for (var i = 0; checkbox.length; ++i) {
```

You should iterate your loop like this,

```
for (var i = 0; i<checkbox.length-1; i++) {
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
         menuId = checkbox[i].value;
         checkslist.push(menuId);
    }
}
```

And your alert should be,

```
alert(checkslist[0] )
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/xagudezozo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all checkboxes and add them to the array like this `list.push(($(this).prop("checked")));` checked returns either true or false if the box is checked

```js
function getList() {
  var list = []
  $.each($("input:checkbox"), function() {
    list.push(($(this).prop("checked")));    
  });
  console.log(list)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<button onClick="getList()">Get list</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the checked values to appear in your alert you should combine them into a string. This function gets all checkboxes with the class "checks" as in your example function, adds those values that are checked to an array and creates a string for the alert that contains all checked values.
The array of values is returned, in case you want to use that somewhere else.

```
function getChecked(){
    let checks = document.getElementsByClassName("checks");
    let checked_values = [];
    let checked_values_string = "";
    for(let i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
        if(checks[i].checked){
            checked_values.push(checks[i].value);
            checked_values_string = checked_values_string + checks[i].value + " ";
        }
    }
    alert(checked_values_string);
    return checked_values;
}
```